# Ask for password when logging in using Google Sign-In API

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I've integrated **Google's Sign-In** `API` on my Android App and it is working fine with its "out of the box" functionalities. Now, I would like it to prompt users to re-authenticate whenever they are linking a Google account (by supplying its credentials). This is to ensure that the one linking the account is indeed its owner.

I've searched related posts and they say this feature is not yet present on the current `API`.

I hope someone has an idea on how could I implement this.

Comment: I am facing the exact same situation. How did you resolve this?