# Google does not ask for password when signing back in

Tags: java, android, rest, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to upload a ZIP file generated by my App to user's Google Drive.
And so far a user can sign in Google by using the REST API without problem.

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
```

But my App is not designed for just one single user.
When the next user comes and generates his own ZIP file, he may want to sign in with his own Google account and upload the file to his own Google Drive.
Thus I also implemented the sign-out code.

```
    private void signOut() {
        String currentGoogleAccountDisplayName = "";
        if(mGoogleSignInClient == null) {
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        }

        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
        if(account != null) {
            currentGoogleAccountDisplayName = account.getDisplayName();
        }
        final String msg = "Revoke account \"" + currentGoogleAccountDisplayName + "\" access completed.";

        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this,
                        (@NonNull Task<Void> task) -> {
                            // Show sign-out message
                        });


    }
```

But Google seems to cache the account who has ever signed in.
And later users can sign in previous user's Google account by simply pressing other user's account without being asked for authentication (In most cases, entering a password).
In this case, users can upload the ZIP file to previous users' Google Drive, which is a serious security breach.

I tried

```
    mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();
```

and

```
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
```

Neither of them request later users provide authentication again.

I also found that some answers mentioned

```
    GoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
```

But this API is deprecated.
And there isn't something like `.requestPassword()`in `GoogleSignInOptions`.

Is there a proper way to sign out a user, and prompt authentication (i.e. ask him to enter his password) every time he tries to sign back in again using REST API?

A similar question (but no answer) is found here --
[Ask for password when logging in using Google Sign-In API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791109/ask-for-password-when-logging-in-using-google-sign-in-api)